# Port Forwarding vs Port Triggering for online game Elder Scrolls Online

Tags: ports, port-forwarding

My system is Windows 10 on a TP-Link WDR3600 router (no VPN).  I use this computer for banking and other important things.  I'm no network engineer but I've heard port forwarding puts you more at risk and would like to know your thoughts vs port triggering.  I'm not even sure I got the port forwarding working (I believe it was successful).

Secondly how do I check if the ports are open while gaming and port triggering?  Open Port Check Tool does not seem to work so I grabbed Simple Port Forwarding exe, which I'm not sure works for the port triggering. Do I need to somehow track which ports are open while running the game?
My understanding is that port triggering will only open the ports when my computer 'asks' for the port via my game initializing.  After the game closes, the ports get closed as well. Is this right?

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot recommend products/services and your VPN question was too undefined to be able to answer.

Comment: Port forwarding is more of a networking question than a security question. Port forwarding is as secure as the service listening on that port. Checking for open ports requires that you test on the other side of the firewall. There are tons of online tools that can do this for you.